# How i can update parameter in the current model if it is not passed in strong parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Selling with 3 parameters (copies, selled_copies, remaining_copies)
and i have SellingsController looks like this:

```
def update 
  @selling = Selling.find(params[:id])
   @selling.update(selling_params)
   render json: @selling 
end

  private
 def selling_params
   params.require(:selling).permit(:copies, :selled_copies) 
end
```

When i send PATCH request with 2 parameters (copies and selled_copies) i want to update one more parameter in the current model: remaining_copies (the value of this must be: copies – selled_copies) and i want to write this value in db too.
May you hint how i can implement this?

Comment: Separated routes for `patch` and `put` so they both can get their own action in `SellingsController`. Then in the `patch` action do a `merge!`; `selling_params.merge!({remaining_copies: selling_params[:copies] - selling_params[:selled_copies]})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your selling model:

```
class Selling < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :count_remaining_copies

  def count_remaining_copies
   self.update_columns(remaining_copies: self.copies - self.selled_copies)
  end
end
```

Use `update_columns` instead of `update`, so you don't trigger this callback endlessly (*stack level too deep error*).

I chosed the `after_update` callback but you could use another, please see:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html